# how to find a text in a file in UNIX without using grep command

Tags: grep

Is there any other way to find a text in a way without grep command from multiple files.

This was asked in one of my interview but I could find a possible solution for this question.

Answer (score 5):

Numerous unix commands incorporate the functionality of grep, allowing a grep-like command to be implemented.  Some obvious examples:

`awk`:

```
awk '/pattern/'
```

`sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/pattern/p'
```

`perl`:

```
perl -n -e 'print if (/pattern/)'
```

Comment: Ooh, `ex` with `g/re/p`!

Comment: Thank you for response. I think I should try more complex scenarios.